# Cassandra nodes goes down after starting

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have built the 3 node cluster in aws and after I shutting down the cassandra service, my sys admin has took the image of one node and made 3 another nodes for new data center. I have done the config changes in 3 new nodes and started one by one. First one started without any issues, second node joined the cluster has been displayed on nodetool status /ring of other nodes then automatically went down. When I checked logs it says below errors. I don't know why the other node in its data center is shown down in errors eventhough it is properly running and been shown in all other original 3 nodes as UP.  Is this due to taking image as its only occuring when I took the images( this is second time i took images) or anything I missed to clear off?

```
O  20:44:46  JOINING: Starting to bootstrap...
ERROR 20:44:46  Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.160.48.102).  If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:244) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:132) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:72) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1143) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:933) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:729) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:611) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:377) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:329) ~[dse-4.7.3.jar:4.7.3]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:530) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.689.jar:2.1.8.689]
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:75) [dse-4.7.3.jar:4.7.3]
java.lang.RuntimeException: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.160.48.102).  If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.getAllRangesWithStrictSourcesFor(RangeStreamer.java:244)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.RangeStreamer.addRanges(RangeStreamer.java:132)
        at org.apache.cassandra.dht.BootStrapper.bootstrap(BootStrapper.java:72)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.bootstrap(StorageService.java:1143)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:933)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:729)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:611)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:377)
        at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:329)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:530)
        at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:75)
Exception encountered during startup: A node required to move the data consistently is down (/10.160.48.102).  If you wish to move the data from a potentially inconsistent replica, restart the node with -Dcassandra.consistent.rangemovement=false
INFO  20:44:46  DSE shutting down...
INFO  20:44:46  All plugins are stopped.
WARN  20:44:46  No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
INFO  20:44:46  Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  20:44:46  MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
```

Comment: What does nodetool status say about the node?  And did you clean the Data directories from the image ? Is the 10.x.x.102 one of the new nodes or the node that an image was taken from ?

Comment: HI.. Thanks for replying, the nodetool status says the node is up and running, i removed all the data directories before starting the service, x.x.102 is clone of the us nodes (original servers). I tried the rotation, 101 and 104( another 2 images) but they say the same. basically all the image nodes are having this problem.I just kept auto_bootstrap: false and it joins the cluster good now. but i am worried if i run nodetool repair again it will go down.